# My React front-end is unable to call my node-express backend server, the fullstack app is deployed in heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, deployment

```
const port = process.env.PORT || ("http://localhost:3002")
const postUrl=`${port}/post`;
addData=()=>{
    console.log(postUrl)
    console.log(process.env,"AS")
    Axios.post(postUrl,this.state.form)
    .then((response)=>{
    this.setState({errorMessage:"",successMessage:response.data})})
    .catch((err)=>{      
      this.setState({successMessage:"",errorMessage:err.response.data.message})
    })
  }
```

**When I am calling the backend in the production process.env.PORT is blank.**

(process.env.NODE_EV= production which is absolutely correct exactly like in the backend)

My backend is completely fine as it getting the process.env.PORT correctly.
But my frontend is not getting the process.env.PORT that's why it keeps calling the other address("http://localhost:3002").

App will completely work fine if I keep open my local machine backend because the "http://localhost:3002"
is available to serve. But in production, Heroku keeps changing the process.env.PORT which is showing its value in the backend, not in the frontend

How can I make my frontend to call my backend server properly in production??

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const port = process.env.PORT || 3002;

const cors = require("cors");
const path=require("path");
const routing  = require("./routing/route");
require('dotenv').config();
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use("/",routing);

app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  console.log("hii")
  res.status(500).send({ message: err.message });
});

if(process.env.NODE_ENV ==="production"){

  app.use(express.static("client/build"));

  app.get("*",(req,res)=>{
       res.sendFile(path.resolve((__dirname,"client","build","index.html")));
  });
}

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(` Server is started at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

server file

Comment: Wait, is your React application served from your Node.JS application?

Comment: Yes, React application served my Node.JS application. What else I can share to help u

Comment: Your React app is running in your user's browser, **not** on your server. It doesn't have access to the environment variables on the server. Also it's not on the same machine at all, so can't access the backend by port alone anyway. Have a look at this starter kit I put together for full stack JS, it runs on Heroku fine: https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit/wiki/Architecture

Comment: so why is it that "process.env.NODE_EV= production" because this env is also on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your React application is served from your Node.JS application as you said, you could just use [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location). [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) is an object that stores statistics about the current page that the user is on, and you could use that to construct a URL and send the server a request, like so:

```js
// This URL uses a template literal, which is a new feature of ES6.
// All but Internet Explorer supports it.
// This is using window.location.protocol, which is either `http:` or `https:`,
// depending on the protocol that the page was loaded with. window.location.host
// is the host that the page was loaded from, with the port number.
const postUrl =
  `${window.location.protocol}//${window.location.host}/post`;

// And then requesting with the URL.
addData = () => {
  console.log(postUrl);
  console.log(process.env, "AS");
  Axios.post(postUrl, this.state.form)
    .then((response) => {
      this.setState({errorMessage: "",successMessage: response.data});
    })
    .catch((err) => {      
      this.setState({successMessage: "",errorMessage: err.response.data.message});
    });
}
```

Comment: window.location.host is giving me the address at which the app is hosted not any port number. I will be updating my question with the server code so that u can correct me nabout.....i""s your React application served from your Node.JS application""

Comment: Yes, and if the React application is served using the same URL as your Node.JS server, that will work.

Comment: console.log(` Server is started at http://localhost:${port}`); the output of it suggesting me that React and node are not using the same url

Comment: @PiyushRaj localhost is **on Heroku**, your clients aren't accessing the frontend *or* backend on their *own* localhost.

Comment: Here's an article that explains it further: http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/paths/elevate/how_heroku_works.html

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes, then how can I call my server side

Comment: You have to do it using a relative route (as shown in that starter kit), where the backend serves the frontend, or by calling it on the public herokuapp.com address.

Comment: Thanks, Everyone for helping its working. This is my first project in Heroku u guys really helped and providing materials to read and understand the concepts more thoroughly.